# If it's inside the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

I have a simple question for you. I have a variable with my url. Now i want check this url. I make this javascript:

```
var url = "http://www.mikevierwind.nl";

if(url == "localhost" ) {
    alert("test");
}
```

How can i make the follow thing. When mikewind is in variable. Than run it. The variable can also be mikevierwind.be and mikevierwind.eu. But the script must always than run. I must check of mikevierwind is in the variable.

Comment: You just need to check the URL [substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (url.indexOf("mikevierwind") >= 0 ) {
  alert("test")
}
```

Comment: That comparison should really be `!= -1` rather than `> 0`, since the position in the string doesn't matter.

Comment: `indexOf()` may return 0 if the string starts with `mikevierwind`. While I appreciate that it shouldn't as a URL, this should be noted for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care if `mikevierwind` is *in* the string, use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var url = "http://www.mikevierwind.nl";

if(url.indexOf('mikevierwind') != -1) {
    alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var url = "http://www.mikevierwind.nl";

if(url.indexOf('mikevierwind') != -1) {
    alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of local host

```
var url = "http://www.mikevierwind.nl";

if(url == document.location.href ) {
    alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "mikewind.bet";
alert(s.indexOf("mikewind") != -1);
//indexOf returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core%5FJavaScript%5F1.5%5FReference/Objects/String/indexOf

```
var str="This is testing for javascript search !!!";
if(str.search("for") != -1) {
   //logic
}
```